# Cannot get AWS Elastic Beanstalk single instance (no load balancer) to listen on 443

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

No matter what I do I cannot get my application to listen on port 443 (https). I simply need nginx to forward traffic to my app which is running https on port 8080, but nginx will only listen on port 80 and will refuse to forward to my app unless it is also running on port 80.

I've followed the instructions in [this article](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html) but it makes no difference.

I do not have a domain name yet, I am simply using a self signed cert so I don't believe certbot will help here.

Please help I am so frustrated hahaaaaaa

Comment: what is your `nginx.conf`?

Comment: @user973254 right now it is the default one generated by aws elastic beanstalk, but for awhile I was trying to use the one provided in the article i linked. Only thing I changed in it was this line:
              proxy_pass  https://localhost:8080;

Comment: so your `nginx` listens on `80` port, not on `443` as stated in config you've linked?

Comment: You also need your own domain and valid public ssl certificate. Do you have then?

Comment: @user973254 in the config I linked It says `listen       443;`

Comment: @Marcin in my post: `I do not have a domain name yet, I am simply using a self signed cert so I don't believe certbot will help here.`

Comment: @PatrickWilbur then I do not understand your configuration and when goals are you trying to achieve. You've said that `I cannot get my application to listen on port 443 (https)` and now you are saying that nginx is listening on 443 (https) port. Too little details and lack of needed configuration files.